# Remove a dynamically added element/template from a hierarchy (in AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs

I have a piece of AngularJs code which adds a group of elements in a hierarchical manner. Also it deletes a group elements on the respective button clicks.

The problem I have is I am unable to delete/remove a node if it does not have any children.

In the delete function I tried to empty the node still the node is not getting removed.

Script.js :

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('nestedController', function($scope){            
             $scope.delete = function(data) {

                 if(data.nodes.length  == 0)
                 {
                  data = {};
                 }
               // Removes all the children nodes. 
               data.nodes = [];
            };    
...
});
```

html:

```
  <html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="nestedController">

  <head>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-tmpl">
  {{data.name}}
  ...
  <button class="btn" ng-click="delete(data)" >Delete nodes</button>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'my-tmpl'"></li>
  </ul>
 </script>   
  </head>

  <body>
<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'my-tmpl'"></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Fully functional code is in the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UR7tzD47qPQWaqBmmhPN?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

With your code you can not delete a single node, because the delete function that you implemented deletes only the child elements of a node and not the parent itself. If you want to delete only a single child node you have to build another function that takes in input the node itself and removes it from the `tree` data structure. If you implement such a function consider also to recusively delete the child nodes.